# Remove record from sys.objects?

Tags: sql-server, etl

I ran a `ALTER SCHEMA ...` on a  table (SQL Server 2012 SP1) but the `sys.objects` record is still there. When I run the ETL I get an error that the table doesn't exist anymore because it's trying to remove all constraints. This one is of type PK Primary Key Constraint. How can I safely remove the record from the `sys.objects` table?

I managed to fix this issue by scripting the database to a new one, `ALTER SCHEMA ...` again on that table to bring it back to `dbo.`, then `DROP` and recreate the table in the different table schema.

Comment: To drop a primary key constraint, the syntax is `ALTER TABLE your-table DROP CONSTRAINT your-constraint-name`.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the reply but the table doesn't exist anymore. I have moved it from one table schema to another one but the sys.objects table didn't get update to reflect that. Running your command I get: Cannot find the object "MY_TABLE_NAME" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Comment: try this query select * from sysobjects where object_name(id) = 'yourtable' and take care schema owner. Because can be possible your table exist in other schema (not dbo)

Comment: Probably haven't explained the problem well enough. I had a table `dbo.MY_TABLE` with a PK constraint that I moved using `ALTER SCHEMA ..` to `RAW.MY_TABLE` but `sys.objects` didn't get updated!?. My ETL is trying to remove all constraints but fails, because table `dbo.MY_TABLE` that is still in `sys.objects` doesn't actually exist anymore. All subsequent `ALTER` and `DROP` commands fail with `...because it does not exist...`,

Comment: All schema related fields `sysobjects.schema_ver, sysobjects.base_schema_ver, sysobjects.stats_schema_ver` return 0.

Comment: When you transfer a table from one schema to another using `ALTER SCHEMA...TRANSFER`, dependent constraints should also get transferred to the new schema.  Run this query to verify: `SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS schema_name, name, type_desc FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) = N'RAW';`.  Perhaps your ETL process is still referencing the old schema name instead of RAW?